# How do I write this JPQL query with subquery?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, subquery, jpql

I'm trying to traduce that SQL sentence

```
SELECT 
  operationalobjective.idoperationalobjective, 
  pno_oo.name
FROM 
  public.operationalobjective, 
  public.policynamedobject pno_oo
WHERE
  pno_oo.idpolicynamedobject = operationalobjective.idoperationalobjective AND
  operationalobjective.idoperationalobjective NOT IN
(
SELECT 
  operationalobjective.idoperationalobjective  
FROM 
  public.operationalobjective, 
  public.goal, 
  public.policy, 
  public.policynamedobject pno_oo, 
  public.policynamedobject pno_p
WHERE 
  goal.idpolicy = policy.idpolicy AND
  goal.idoperationalobjective = operationalobjective.idoperationalobjective AND
  pno_oo.idpolicynamedobject = operationalobjective.idoperationalobjective AND
  pno_p.idpolicynamedobject = policy.idpolicy AND
  policy.idpolicy = <number>
);
```

Having in mind Policy and OperationalObjective both extends PolicyNamedObject, I'm trying to traduce that into JPQL:

```
SELECT oo FROM OperationalObjective oo 
WHERE oo.idoperationalobjective NOT IN 
(
   SELECT oo.idoperationalobjective 
   FROM OperationalObjective oo, Goal g, Policy p 
   WHERE g.policy = :policy AND g.operationalobjective = oo AND p = :policy
)
```

But when I execute that query via JPA, it raises an exception saying:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table <<t5>>  
  SELECT t7.idpolicynamedobject, t7.type, t7.description, t7.name, t0.idoperationalobjective, t0.idobjectivescategory 
    FROM public.OperationalObjective t0 INNER JOIN public.PolicyNamedObject t7 ON t0.idoperationalobjective = t7.idpolicynamedobject 
    WHERE (NOT (t0.idoperationalobjective IN 
    (
        SELECT t5.idoperationalobjective 
            FROM public.OperationalObjective t1 CROSS JOIN public.Goal t2 CROSS JOIN public.policy t3 
                INNER JOIN public.PolicyNamedObject t4 ON t3.idpolicy = t4.idpolicynamedobject 
                INNER JOIN public.PolicyNamedObject t6 ON t5.idoperationalobjective = t6.idpolicynamedobject, public.OperationalObjective t5 
            WHERE (t2.idpolicy = ? AND t2.idoperationalobjective = t5.idoperationalobjective 
                AND t3.idpolicy = ?) AND t6.type = ?))) AND t7.type = ?} [code=0, state=42P01]
```

I've executed the SQL sentence using PgAdmin and it retrieved what I wanted, but I don't know what I am doing wrong translating it into JPQL... any idea?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will need to refactor your JPQL statement to use subquery 'EXISTS' as the IN statement doesn't support a sub select. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT oo FROM OperationalObjective oo 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT oosub
   FROM OperationalObjective oosub
   JOIN oosub.goal g 
   JOIN g.policy p   
   WHERE <<where conditions>> 
)
```

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_exists)